# Compiler doesn’t locate GCD header file on Windows

Tags: c, windows, grand-central-dispatch

I need to use Grand Central Dispatch in my program but I don’t know how to use it on Windows.

The error I’m getting is

> error: dispatch/dispatch.h: No such file or directory

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

        dispatch_group_t group;
        dispatch_queue_t queue;    // thread queues to use

        group = dispatch_group_create();

        queue= dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);

        dispatch_sync(queue, ^{ 
                                  puts("Dispatch test"); 
                                } ); 


        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


        dispatch_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That error typically indicates that you didn't install GCD. Which version of GCD were you planning to use, [libXDispatch](http://opensource.mlba-team.de/xdispatch/) or [DrPizza](https://github.com/DrPizza/libdispatch)?

Comment: I downloaded libxDispatch but i am not sure where to place it..

Comment: You need to put the header files someplace your compiler looks for header files or you need to configure your compiler to look for header files wherever you placed the GCD header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Portable libdispatch](https://www.heily.com/trac/libdispatch)
- [[libdispatch-dev] Lion libdispatch sources posted & next steps for  macosforge repo](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/libdispatch-dev/2011-August/000589.html)

You might be able to use GCD API (libdispatch) on Windows. However, for Blocks, Blocks supported compiler(gcc with Apple's patch or LLVM clang) is needed.